# Connection to MySQL server fails

Tags: mysql, networking, database-connection

I'm trying to access a database from the default Linux MySQL client, but all I get is a timeout. It's actually the database used by a WordPress website, and in the configuration file I can see that the IP address of the DB server is actually localhost (127.0.0.1). So I assume that the host name of the DB server is the same as the website's.

I am able to connect to the database with a PHP script that I wrote and uploaded to the server with this same information, and with the **show variables** query I was able to verify the port number (which was 3306) and specify it to the client. I can see a lot of variables but I'm not sure which one to use.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If your Wordpress site is remote, you must connect to DB server like remote connection not local connection. If wordpress and DB server are in the same server, the configuration file to connect with DB is localhost, but if you want connect from remote host you must config your connecto with remote data.

Comment: I know, that's why I said in the post "I assume that the host name of the DB server is the same as the website's". Actually the domain name I'm using in the "the same as the website's"

Comment: Try to check if mysql is alive with telnet from a linux terminal (for example): telnet «hostname» 3306

Comment: It keeps "trying", I'll probably get a timeout soon.